# MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [amazonaws.com:27017] on first connect [Error: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, apache2.2, aws-documentdb

I have my mongo details in Apache config file. And getting this error.

SetEnv MONGO_URL mongodb://:@XXXXXXXXX.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/?ssl=true&ssl_ca_certs=/home/ec2-user/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem&replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false

```
        App 2291 output: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [XXXXXX.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017] on first connect [Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
        App 2291 output:     at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1474:34)
        App 2291 output:     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:310:20)
        App 2291 output:     at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
        App 2291 output:     at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:917:8)
        App 2291 output:     at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:687:12) {
        App 2291 output:   name: 'MongoNetworkError',
        App 2291 output:   [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
        App 2291 output: }]
```

MongoNetworkError:  [Error: unable to get local issuer certificate

Comment: Hi Yaseen, are you using SSH tunneling or is your application connecting from a client inside the VPC? If you are connecting from outside your VPC with SSH tunneling, you can not set the replicaSet and readPreference for DocumentDB

Comment: Both EC2 & DB are in same vpc. SSH is working fine. This is happening when I try using a meteor app & setting DB from apache or nginx env var

Answer (score 9):

It is fixed. I am supposed to use tls=true&tlsCAFile=/var/www/covidapp/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem instead of ssl=true&ssl_ca_certs=/var/www/medapp/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem

https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongonetworkerror-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate/3518/3

Comment: A note that might help others. Don't forget to restart the service using this. I spent too long figuring this out in node-red thinking pressing deploy in node-red would solve this, no had to restart the service directly on the box.

Answer (score 1):

When TLS is enabled, by default both client and server verify each other's certificates. This means both of them need to have the CA certificate specified that is valid for the certificate the other side presents during handshake, along with any intermediate certificates.

For the node driver, see [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/tutorials/connect/tls/) for what the TLS options are named. `ssl_ca_certs` is not one of them.